# What does "so much as" mean in these three sentences? What grammatical function does this phrase serve?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"I hate wizards. If he so much as points a finger at me, you stick him, Hook."

"Remind me to find out the name of that flooring company so I can be sure never to buy so much as a carpet tile from it."

"I didn’t listen so much as survive the conversation."

Comment: What research have you done? I've posted an answer dealing with your first example. Can you determine the function and meaning of "so much as" in your other two examples?

Comment: @BillJ I got the first sentence from TV show Cursed. I searched "so much as" on line and found there are actually two defintions, but Lexico and Cambridge Dictionary each have their own definition. 
[lexico]https://www.lexico.com/definition/so_much_as
[cambridge]https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so-much-as

Answer (score 2):

"If he/she does so much as [x]" at the beginning of a conditional statement means that [x] is the *minimum* condition to trigger the consequence.

In your specific example "pointing a finger" would result in the threatened action.

Usually, this idiom uses a *deliberately understated* condition. A common example is "if he so much as *looks* at me" when someone doesn't want any contact from a person, or "if you so much as *breathe*" when demanding that someone be silent. In real-life usage, this is just hypobole, and those actions would probably not be punished.

In your example, "pointing a finger" is a pretty innocuous gesture, but as the person referred to is a wizard this could be a gesture connected with casting a spell, so perhaps not an example of hypobole.

Comment: Far too complicated. I suspect the OP wanted something simple. In any case, you haven't answered the OP's question about the grammatical function of "so much as".

Comment: @BillJ "so much as" have a different meaning in the third sentence and it is more like a conjunction rather than degree adjunct if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> *I hate wizards. If he so much as points a finger at me, you stick him*,
> *Hook*.

The grammatical function of the idiom "so much as" is degree adjunct.

The meaning is  similar to "even" or "does no more than", and emphasises to Hook that he is to stick him for even the slightest misdemeanour.

Note that idioms like "so much as" can have different meanings depending on context. Generally, they can only be roughly interpreted.

Comment: Why does Cambridge Dictionary define it as "but rather" only? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so-much-as

Comment: This is incorrect - it doesn't mean "do no more than", it means the opposite - "does as little as".

Comment: @Astralbee "even" doesn't have the negative sense; "so much as" is used with negative. https://www.lexico.com/definition/so_much_as

Comment: @Astralbee Idioms can only be roughly interpreted, and "so much as" can have different interpretations depending on context. Note that I also said "even", which is a perfectly reasonable alternant to "so much as".

Comment: @BillJ Again, not true Bill - idioms have an established meaning through usage. That's what makes them an idiom. Are you perhaps thinking of metaphors?

Comment: @Astralbee Nonsense! In a great many cases, you'll find grammars use the term 'roughly' when giving an interpretation of an idiom that may not have a precise meaning.

Comment: @DenAllan "So much as" can be an NPI (non-affirmative) in, for example. "I couldn't so much as walk, let alone run!"

Comment: Is there a negative sense on the first sentence?

Comment: The Cambridge definition is a slightly different usage: _not so much A as B_, meaning that B is a more appropriate description than the more obvious A. "I didn't so much run up the stairs as scramble up them."

Comment: @KateBunting Was this the first time you saw the phrase used in this sense? Could you understand it before referring to the dictionaries. English is so confusing. In Lexico dictionary, there are 11 example sentences with negative sense to exaplain that it means "even" with negative. But from the sentence I got from the TV show, I don't see there is a negative sense.

Comment: No, that usage is perfectly familiar to me. Many years ago, there was a British TV satire programme called _Not So Much a Programme, More a Way of Life_. The sense of the 'wizard' quote is 'if he threatens me in as small a way as pointing his finger at me'.

Comment: @KateBunting Do you identify the 'wizard' sentence as a negative one or positive one?

Comment: Neither, unless you define 'expressing distrust of wizards' as negative!

Comment: @KateBunting But Lexico states that it's used with negative. https://www.lexico.com/definition/so_much_as

Comment: Yes - _with_ negative, as in "without so much as". That doesn't mean that the _sentence_ is negative, just the word 'without'.

Comment: @KateBunting My point is that the "wizard" sentence doesn't follow the normal and correct usage of "so much as". The phrase needs to pair up with a negative sense. This dictionary explains it more clear: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/so-much-as

Comment: On second thought, I think there is an indication that speaker doesn't want the wizard to point a finger at him. This could be regarded as a negative sense. But it is strange since this is not referring to wizard's intention.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112679/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-den-allan).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the third sentence, which I think is quite different from the first two: "so much as" [can be interchangeable](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/so+much+as) with "as much as."

The sentence might make more sense if we modify it slightly:

> I wasn't listening as much as I was surviving [through] the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

The usage in the third sentence doesn’t seem to have been adequately explained in previous answers.

In this case, separating “So much as” is a red herring. [The full idiom is “not so much A as B,”](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/not-so-much-as), meaning it’s rather B than A. But the form of this expression is quite flexible in that “not” can be absorbed into a contraction, such as “I didn’t” and “so much as” does not have to immediately follow “not”.

Refer to the example sentence in the Cambridge Dictionary web page:

> *I don’t feel angry so much as sad.*

You can see the structure is the same as the third sentence in your post, but now it’s clear that this is a variation of not so much A as B.