# the phrase "so much as"

Tags: meaning

*He will go bananas if you **so much as** scratch the car.*

Can you please explain to me the meaning of the phrase "so much as" in the context of the sentence? Does it mean that s/he is so cautious about the car that in case you scratch it, s/he will go mad?

Comment: If you look in a dictionary, it will tell you that it means "even".

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/259253/what-does-so-much-as-mean-in-these-three-sentences-what-grammatical-function

Comment: @KateBunting: Could you not bring yourself to upvote *either* of the answers to  that earlier question? (I assume you didn't closevote here because we can't cite an earlier question as a duplicate if it's got no upvoted answers.)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Sorry, I didn't realise that that was what I was supposed to do. I tried to close, but wasn't allowed to (and it still won't let me add my vote).

Comment: I don't think anyone would be saying that's what you're *supposed* to do (it's entirely up to each individual whether and why they might up-, down-, or closevote). But it did look like a clear duplicate to me, and when the system wouldn't let me cite that earlier Q as a duplicate (because it had no accepted or upvoted answer) I just went back to it, and upvoted both the (perfectly good, imho) answers there. *Then* the system let me cite it as a duplicate here!

Comment: (Also, I have no idea why "Community" was so impressed with my closevote that (nearly an hour later, apparently) it unilaterally forced the action through, where normally it would need 4 other users or a mod to effect that.)